# How do I remove a Tcl procedure?

Tags: tcl, procedure, undef

How do I remove a tcl procedure?

One can

- `unset` a variable,
- override an alias with `interp alias {} myproc {} otherproc`,
- override a proc with one defined inside another namespace with `namespace import -force`.

But I did not find a way to make a procedure unknown.

Comment: person who voted to close: really? A programming question about a programming language is off-topic to a programming site?

Comment: Seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me. Admittedly, fairly easy to answer with a google search but, to be fair, one of the goals of SO is to BE that result on google search when you look for such an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`rename`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/rename.htm) to delete a proc

```
rename myproc ""
```

Example:

```
% proc myproc {} {
    puts "hello world"
}
% myproc
hello world
% rename myproc ""
% myproc
invalid command name "myproc"
%
```

Comment: For proc's imported from a namespace `rename namespace_name::proc_name` and the locally imported name vanishes, too. Thanks! Life can be so simple sometimes...